# How do I fix missing icon in the program panel with KDE

Tags: launcher, kde, icons

I have created desktop launcher for my CLion environment, it works correctly except icon for the application is missing:

[image]

Here is my system info:

[image]

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: yes, it does'nt help